# bluetooth Hc-05 connection with flutter and arduino uno

Tags: flutter, hc-05

How can send data from MPU6050 sensor and Arduino uno to my Flutter app (android app) using Bluetooth HC-05?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter blue package will work for you. [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue)

Comment: Yes I used it, but I have a problem with Bluetooth HC-05 not appear in my emulator